# Updating nuget package to support xamarin unified

Tags: .net, xamarin, nuget, portable-class-library

I am trying to get my pcl to build properly into a nuget package. I have updated to the xamarin beta and I have updated nuget to version 2.8.5 however I am getting the following error when creating my package:

> Issue: Invalid framework folder.
>
> Description: The folder 'Xamarin.iOS10' under 'lib' is not recognized as a valid framework name or a supported culture identifier.
>
> Solution: Rename it to a valid framework name.

If I just use MonoTouch I don't get the error, nut then the nuget package is not installed correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are not using the latest version of NuGet. The product version needs to be 2.8.3 or above. The assembly version will be 2.8.5.x which can be a bit confusing.

If you are using NuGet.exe then run the following to check the product version:

```
NuGet.exe update -self
```

You should see the output:

```
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.8.3.
NuGet.exe is up to date.
```

Then run:

```
NuGet.exe pack YourNuSpec.nuspec
```

Also note that the invalid framework message is only a warning. The NuGet package will still be created with the correct lib directories even if you are using an old version of NuGet.exe which does not recognise the Xamarin.iOS framework.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for the feedback. I just ran the commands as you suggested and nuget is updated correctly. I also tried to pack it and it worked as a charm locally. But I still have a problem when building the exact same on our buildserver. However your are right that package still gets pushed so I have the possibility of testing it

Comment: God damn u svn. Hi Matt you are correct. I made a mistake and had not comitted the updated version of nuget.exe to svn. I will accept your answer and beat myself with a club.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Has anybody an explanation why and how the Nuget version affects Mono.Touch builds?